# Import json file to mongoDB using python

Tags: python, mongodb

I am getting this error while trying to import:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PythonSC\module21.py", line 8, in <module>
    page = open('c:\restaurants\restaurants.json','r')
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'c:\restaurants\restaurants.json'
```

here is my source code of trying to import:

```
import json
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client.restaurants
collection = db.restaurantsCollection
page = open('c:\restaurants\restaurants.json','r')
dataset = json.loads(page.read())

for item in dataset:
    collection.insert(item)

for item in collection.find():
    print(item)
```

and here is the sample json data from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mongodb/docs-assets/geospatial/restaurants.json

I still could not understand why this error and I hope someone could lend me a helping hand. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `'c:\restaurants\restaurants.json'` -> `r'c:\restaurants\restaurants.json'`? It's possible it wants to read backslashes as escape characters. `r` makes the string "raw", so you don't have to escape backslashes themselves. Always provide regexes and paths as raw strings. And passwords, if entered in the code or the console if entered as a string.

Answer (score 1):

1.Place your json file in your project repository and then use it for reading.

`f= open("[file_name]","r+")`

2.Other way(Second Method) is to use os module to get position of file and use it as
`path=os.getcwd()+[append your file name]
open(path,'r+');`